# Android: httppost, problems checking result

Tags: android, http-post

I'm struggling a bit with checking/verifying the result of a http post operation. I'm checking a database for certain entries, and then converting the result to a JSONArray. However, if the result is null, I don't want to attempt the conversion. I'm catching the exception, so the program doesn't crash if the result is zero, but I'd like to avoid attempting to convert an empty result alltogether.

I'm connecting to the database (via a php script) like this:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    StringBuilder authentication = new 
    StringBuilder().append("user").append(":").append("pass");
    result = Base64.encodeBytes(authentication.toString().getBytes());
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + result);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-
                         8859-1"),8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
```

As you can see, I'm getting the result from the server and converting it to a string.

Then I wan to convert this string into a JSONArray IF it's not empty. If it's empty, I want to skip it.

However, I cannot figure out how to catch if the converted result string if null or not.

If I do this, after the above code,

```
itemsview.append("Result: " + result)
```

then the appended text is "null". Which makes sense, since the returned result from the db (in this test) is blank.

However, if I do this to catch the null result,

```
if (result.equals("null") {
    itemsview.append("Result is null!");
}
```

the text doesn't appear. So, if I print out the value of the result string, it is null. But when I check it for the value null in the if, then it doesn't turn out to be true.

What am I missing here?

BTW: What I'm doing after this code is, as mentioned, converting the result string to JSONArray, then inserting the values into a List

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if (result.equals("null") {
itemsview.append("Result is null!");}
```

use

```
if (result==null) {
itemsview.append("Result is null!");}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, before "equals". Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think better you check for result==null rather than what you are doing :) cheers :)

Comment: Problem is, that doesn't work either. The result is exactly the same: If I print out the result, it's null. If I compare it to null, the comparison turns out false.

Comment: Are you able to print the value or its raising a null pointer exception during print? you cant print a null; You can only print a string which contains the characters "n""u""l""l";

Comment: "itemsview.append("Result: " + result)" <--- this prints a null... (there is also a nullpointer exception AFTER the code I posted, when trying to create a JSONArray from the string.

Comment: To specify: It prinst the text "null".

Comment: So uou're saying this "itemsview.append("Result: " + result)" line prints Result: null isn't it?

Comment: Yes. If I print the result string, it prints "null". If I compare it to null, the comparison is false.

Comment: Please print and see the value of result.length() and tel me